# an algebraically closed field definable in a real closed field

Tags: fields, real-algebra, model-theory

Is it true that an algebraically closed field $k$ definable (in the model theory sense) in a real closed field $\mathcal R$ is the algebraic closure $\mathcal{R}^{alg}=\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{-1})$?

UPDATE: if we prove that the definable set $K \subset \mathcal{R}^n$ that defines $k$ in $\mathcal R$ has the same cardinality as $\mathcal R$ then by categoricity of $ACF_0$ we get that $K$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{R}(\sqrt{-1})$ (which is definable in $\mathcal R$ in an obvious fashion). Would this isomorphism be definable?

Comment: One can define the structure $(\mathbb{C}, +, \cdot)$ in $\mathbb R$, by interpreting $mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}^2$, $+$ as the vector addition, and $(a,b) \cdot (c,d):=(ac-bd,ad+bc)$.  The question is whether this is the only algebraically closed field one can define in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ansrew: Model theoretically, there are several ways to interpret algebraic structures within a given structure: Either by means of definable graphs (as in the example Dmitry mentions) or, more generally, as (definable) quotients of definable graphs (which is the modern approach).

Comment: Andres: as RCF has elimination of imaginaries, interpretable implies definable.

Comment: Dmitry, it is certainly true that the field is the same cardinality as $\mathcal R$ seeing as RCF has no two cardinal models.

Comment: James: interesting, can you reproduce the argument or give a reference?

Comment: I have read this somewhere, but not really thought about it - I think it is contained in "Definable Equivalence Relations on Algebraically Closed Fields" by van den Dries, Marker, and Martin. If I were trying to prove it, I would think by induction on the arity of the definable set, and try to use cell decomposition. Certainly the base case, at least, is clear by O-minimality. 

It seems like cell decomposition should work for the induction.

Comment: I just rolled back an edit which did not seem to introduce significant improvements to a question that was asked and answered long ago

Comment: Here's a proof that RCF has no two cardinal models: Let $R \models \mathrm{RCF}$ and $X$ be an infinite definable subset of $R^n$. As $X$ is infinite there is a coordinate projection $\pi : R^n \to R$ such that $\pi(X)$ is infinite. By o-minimality $\pi(X)$ contains a nonempty open interval $I$, and it's easy to produce a definable surjection $I \to R$. More generally, this shows that any o-minimal expansion of an ordered field is one-cardinal. Even more generally: if $K$ is a first order expansion of a field which admits a definable type V topology and every infinite definable subset of $K$

Comment: has interior then $K$ is one-cardinal. So for example Henselian valued fields of characteristic zero are one-cardinal - here the property of unary sets follows from the usual quantifier elimination results.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is an infinite definable subset of a real closed field $R$ which is a zero-divisor-free ring under operations whose graphs are definable in $R$. Then $A$ is definably isomorphic to one of $R$, $R(\sqrt{-1})$ or the ring of quaternions over $R$. This is a special case of the main result of:

Otero, Peterzil, and Pillay,
On groups and rings definable in o-minimal expansions of real closed fields,
Bull. London Math. Soc. 28 (1996), no. 1, 7–14.